# I need to store passwords with two-way encryption. What is the best way to do this?

Tags: encryption, passwords

I am creating a service that will access a database with passwords to different network devices like routers etc. Service takes users credentials and validates if he or she is allowed to access a particular device. The problem is that there must be an option for some administrator to be able to see the devices' passwords, so I cannot store only hashes. What is the 'safest' practice in such a situation?

The example in which it is needed:

- User uses my application to connect to the device with his own credentials.
- Someone needs to connect to the router via some outside software, eg. Putty, thus needs the device's password.

I have been looking for some solid answer but the solid answer is "Do not store password in DB". Unfortunately, this is not an option in my case.

Comment: It looks like you are creating a password/credential manager. If you search for solutions for that problem, you will find more helpful suggestions.

Comment: Making your own service is going to create some weaknesses. Have you looked at something like Cyberark or Thycotic?

Comment: This question is far clearer. Answer: stop making your own. Just use a password manager that has solved all your problems for you. Lots of managers include team access with varying levels of control.